# User agents not trusting web server due to Let's Encrypt DST Root CA X3 root certificate expiration

Tags: ssl-certificate, node.js, certificate-authority, lets-encrypt

I handle a NodeJS server with an SSL certificate issued by Let's Encrypt. It works on some clients (Safari and Firefox on my macOS) and not others (`curl` on my macOS, Safari on iOS). The notice on iOS is:

```
Not trusted

Expired 30/09/21 07:01:15
```

The notice on `curl` is:

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle" of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file using the --cacert option.
```

Inspecting the certificate shows that dates are valid. I found [this warning](https://docs.certifytheweb.com/docs/kb/kb-202109-letsencrypt/) from Let's Encrypt:

> The DST Root CA X3 root certificate expired September 30 14:01:15 2021 GMT.
>
> ...
>
> If your site is working for most devices but not for some, the problem is with their trust store (their list of trusted root certificate).
>
> ...
>
> macOS, iOS etc
>
> Some operating systems hold onto the expired R3 > DST Root CA X3 chain even if your server is no longer using it. Try a restart of the affected client device.

I forced a renewal of the certificate, copied the private key and the full chain to the NodeJS location, and restarted the server. I restarted the iOS device. The new date shows on my browsers and on the iOS device. But the iOS device still does not trust the website.

The website is [www.emotionathletes.og](http://www.emotionathletes.og) .

How can I ensure that all clients get the right certificate chain and can visit the website?

Comment: see also: https://serverfault.com/questions/1079199/client-on-debian-9-erroneously-reports-expired-certificate-for-letsencrypt-issue https://serverfault.com/questions/1079234/since-sep-30-140115-2021-gmt-any-software-using-openssl-1-0-like-curl-php

Comment: Your website https://emotionathletes.org/ is working in newest versions of Chrome, Safari, and Firefox on macOS and Safari on iOS. Are you having trouble with very old devices? As for `curl`, you may need to update the certificates it uses to verify TLS connections, see instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69413675/277303

Answer (score 2):

Since you can't control your clients then the safest way would be to start using some other CA issued certificates.

One possible CA would be ZeroSSL (https://zerossl.com). They offer also certificates via ACME protocol without any fee like Let's Encrypt (https://zerossl.com/letsencrypt-alternative/) and have a pretty good compatibility with older devices (https://help.zerossl.com/hc/en-us/articles/360058294074-ZeroSSL-Compatibility-List).

If you're already using certbot command line tool to manage your Let's Encrypt certificates then you can add few additional switches to it to start issuing ZeroSSL certificates instead:

```
$ certbot ... --server https://acme.zerossl.com/v2/DV90 --eab-kid XXX --eab-hmac-key YYY
```

You can get the `--eab-kid` and `--eab-hmac-key` values from ZeroSSL website after you've registered an account for yourself.