# wget doesn't accept HTTPS certificate (from letsencrypt) on some computers but does on others

Tags: apache-2.4, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, certbot, wget

I have the following situation:

On my www server (`Apache2`, `Debian armhf`) I have HTTPS certificate from `letsencrypt.org` by `certbot`.
When accessing the server from a browser (`Firefox`, `Chromium`) everything was fine, but when I tried `git` or `wget` then the HTTPS certificate was not acccepted.

But this I could observe only on some of the computers I tried this but not on others.
Output from 5 computers:
computer 0 and 4 (not working):

```
0.b:~> wget https://rnk.bicyclesonthemoon.info
--2023-05-12 00:12:47--  https://rnk.bicyclesonthemoon.info/
Resolving rnk.bicyclesonthemoon.info (rnk.bicyclesonthemoon.info)... 192.168.1.4
Connecting to rnk.bicyclesonthemoon.info (rnk.bicyclesonthemoon.info)|192.168.1.4|:443... connected.
ERROR: The certificate of ‘rnk.bicyclesonthemoon.info’ is not trusted.
ERROR: The certificate of ‘rnk.bicyclesonthemoon.info’ has expired.
```

```
4.b:~> wget https://rnk.bicyclesonthemoon.info
--2023-05-12 02:14:32--  https://rnk.bicyclesonthemoon.info/
Resolving rnk.bicyclesonthemoon.info (rnk.bicyclesonthemoon.info)... 192.168.1.4
Connecting to rnk.bicyclesonthemoon.info (rnk.bicyclesonthemoon.info)|192.168.1.4|:443... connected.
ERROR: The certificate of ‘rnk.bicyclesonthemoon.info’ is not trusted.
ERROR: The certificate of ‘rnk.bicyclesonthemoon.info’ has expired.
```

Computers 1, 2, and 6 (working)

```
1a.b:/botm/tmp> wget https://rnk.bicyclesonthemoon.info
--2023-05-12 00:06:07--  https://rnk.bicyclesonthemoon.info/
Resolving rnk.bicyclesonthemoon.info (rnk.bicyclesonthemoon.info)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to rnk.bicyclesonthemoon.info (rnk.bicyclesonthemoon.info)|127.0.0.1|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 226 [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html’

index.html          100%[===================>]     226  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2023-05-12 00:06:07 (732 KB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [226/226]
```

```
2.b:~> wget https://rnk.bicyclesonthemoon.info
--2023-05-12 02:17:10--  https://rnk.bicyclesonthemoon.info/
Resolving rnk.bicyclesonthemoon.info (rnk.bicyclesonthemoon.info)... 192.168.1.4
Connecting to rnk.bicyclesonthemoon.info (rnk.bicyclesonthemoon.info)|192.168.1.4|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 226 [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html’

index.html          100%[===================>]     226  --.-KB/s    in 0.005s  

2023-05-12 02:17:10 (46.6 KB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [226/226]
```

```
6.b:~> wget https://rnk.bicyclesonthemoon.info
--2023-05-12 02:18:01--  https://rnk.bicyclesonthemoon.info/
Resolving rnk.bicyclesonthemoon.info (rnk.bicyclesonthemoon.info)... 192.168.1.4
Connecting to rnk.bicyclesonthemoon.info (rnk.bicyclesonthemoon.info)|192.168.1.4|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 226 [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html’

index.html          100%[===================>]     226  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2023-05-12 02:18:01 (15.7 MB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [226/226]
```

What's interesting is that computers 2 and 4 have the same OS (Debian 10, but 2 is 32 bit, 4 is 64 bit), the same version of `wget` (1.21.2) and are in the same local network, and still on one of them (2) the certificate is accepted and on the other one (4) not

Below is the relevant `apache` configuration:

In `/etc/apache2/sites-available/botm.conf`:

```
# Manage BOTM sites externally:
IncludeOptional /botm/etc/www/sites/*.conf
```

In `/botm/etc/www/sites/rnk.bicyclesonthemoon.info-ssl.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName rnk.bicyclesonthemoon.info
    Include /botm/etc/www/conf/ssl-certbot-botm.conf
    Include /botm/etc/www/conf/rnk.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

In `/botm/etc/www/conf/ssl-certbot-botm.conf`:

```
SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateKeyFile /botm/etc/certbot/live/botm/privkey.pem
SSLCertificateFile /botm/etc/certbot/live/botm/cert.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /botm/etc/certbot/live/botm/chain.pem
```

Originally, I didn't have `SSLCertificateChainFile` included and was told that this is the reason. But adding this did not help.
Also I have seen somewhere that I should use `fullchain.pem` instead but this doesn't help anything either.

At this point I am confused and I don't know how to continue, how to debug, solve.

Comment: Check the versions of OpenSSL and ca-certificates, and whether there are any local/manual changes to ca-certificates (i.e. certs added or removed), especially on 2 and 4 (the most mysterious) and maybe all. LetsEncrypt to support old phones continues to use a cert chain that links to DST Root CA X3 which has expired, but _most_ systems (and all browsers) 'shortcut' this chain to the ISRG Root which is valid; your systems might not if they either don't have ISRG Root or do have OpenSSL 1.0.2 which mishandles this, but Debian 10 _shouldn't_. Compare https://serverfault.com/questions/1079199/ .

Comment: `At this point I am confused`. The problem is 100% on the clients, and the problem is the certificate is not trusted.

Comment: You need to follow the certificate validation process and determine which of the many steps are failing. This differs per platform. A packet capture would also help for reviewing the CDP/AIA/OCSP traffic. https://www.baeldung.com/linux/validating-certificates-curl